# in R how to apply a value of a column to multiple columns in the same data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have a dataframe (df) like this

```
n   g    count  s_a s_b s_c .....
T1 gb    10000   0    1   0
T1 ga,gb 15000   1    1   0
```

And I looked at the values in s_a ... s_n to see which is the highest n

```
top_n <- names(sort(colSums(df[4:ncol(df]), decreasing=TRUE))[1:n]
```

Values of top_n are column name that has colsum(colname) in the top N

I want to use the results of top_n to update each column whose name  = to top_n with the value in column count

```
n   g    count  s_a    s_b    s_c .....
T1 gb    10000   0     10000   0
T1 ga,gb 15000   15000 15000   0
```

Comment: `df[, -1:-3] <- df$count * df[, -1:-3]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the columns of interest (`4:ncol(df)`) , multiply it with the 'count' and assign the output back to the original columns.

```
df[4:ncol(df)] <- lapply(df[4:ncol(df)], `*`, df$count)
```

Or with `Map`, we can do the same by multiplying the corresponding elements

```
df[4:ncol(df)] <- Map(`*`, df[4*ncol(df)], list(df$count))
```

---

Using `data.table v1.9.7`, we can do an `lapply` based method (similar to first `base R` method).  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), specify the columns of interest in `.SDcols`, loop though the columns, multiply with the 'count', and assign (`:=`) the output back to the original columns.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, (4:ncol(df)) := lapply(.SD, `*`, count), .SDcols = 4:ncol(df)]
```